# onclick open table in new window using JS

Tags: javascript

toggleSideBar opens column below `<td>`, but I want to open that in a new window using JS.

```
<input type="button" id="togglebox" value="List Annotations" onclick="toggleSideBar()" />

<td id="PaneContainerRight" class="rightpanel-div-right" style="display: none">
    <div id="annotationPanel" class="PanelEntry">
        <ul class="taskpanel touch" id="CommentPanel">
            <div class="annotationPanelTitleBar">
                <span class="taskPaneTitle" id="CommentPanelTitle">Annotations</span>       
            </div> 
            <div>
                <form style="display:block">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="visibility: hidden">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="listComments" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;">
                <table id="ListTable"></table>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: What does toggleSideBar() look like? If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for window.open()

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
```

The way you can gerenate `table` on newly opened document.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Raidri - Added a small pieces of code. May be now you can remove your down vote :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for Javascript's window.open command

Read more about it (see various examples) here:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471221

Comment: while the link may contain the answer, it's better to post the relevant code in your answer.